# Making text size bigger in div class

Tags: html, css

Please help me with making a text size bigger with style in the following code.

```
<div class="hidden-overlay"> MASTER CLASS AIR 2.0 TITANIUM </div>
```

Comment: have you tried any solution ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do here.  How big is "bigger"? What have you looked at?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this by adding a modifier for the class, allowing you to change the font size, respectively, the current font size (%, em, rem), or you can specify a static size for example 20px,

```
<div class="hidden-overlay hidden-overlay--large-percent"> MASTER CLASS AIR 2.0 TITANIUM </div>
<style>
    .hidden-overlay--large-percent{font-size: 150%}
    .hidden-overlay--large-rem{font-size: 1.5rem}
    .hidden-overlay--large-rem{font-size: 1.5em}
    .hidden-overlay--large-px{font-size: 20px}
</style>
```

for hover effect

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
   <img src="some-img.jpg">
   <div class="hidden-overlay <div class="hidden-overlay hidden-overlay--large-percent">MASTER CLASS AIR 2.0 TITANIUM</div>
<div>
<style>
    .img-wrapper:hover .hidden-overlay--large-percent{color: blue}
    .img-wrapper:hover .hidden-overlay--large-rem{color: #00f}
    .img-wrapper:hover .hidden-overlay--large-rem{color: #00f}
    .img-wrapper:hover .hidden-overlay--large-px{color: #00f}
</style>
```

Comment: it worked. Can you help me with changing the overlay colour too? Now its showing dark grey colour overlay on the image and I want to change the colour of the overlay to full blue colour(No opacity) with text on hover.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to do it from style in the div you've provided, you can try this:

```
<div class="hidden-overlay" style="font-size: 20px;"> MASTER CLASS AIR 2.0 TITANIUM </div>
```

`style` attribute is added to div in which you can write regular css code.

If you want to apply to several places in HTML then you'll have to use CSS classes.

Comment: it worked. Can you help me with changing the overlay colour too? Now its showing dark grey colour overlay on the image and I want to change the colour of the overlay to full blue colour(No opacity) with text on hover.

Comment: @WhiteDotSports If you have your overlay style already written, simply added the property: background-color: blue; to your style. Otherwise, please open a new question and put its link here so we can track the solution.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to simply set the font size for everything in the div like so:

```
<div class="hidden-overlay" style="font-size: 3em;"> MASTER CLASS AIR 2.0 TITANIUM </div>
```

A nicer way of doing it would be to make the text a heading by nesting it in an h1 (maybe try and h2 or h3 aswell)

```
<div class="hidden-overlay"><h1>MASTER CLASS AIR 2.0 TITANIUM</h1></div>
```

see a live sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jr6a95su/1/).

Extra Note: If you didn't want this css to be inline instead of `style="font-size: 3em;"` you could just apply this css to the class `hidden-overlay` like so:

```
<style>
.hidden-overlay {
  font-size: 2em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it worked. Can you help me with changing the overlay colour too? Now its showing dark grey colour overlay on the image and I want to change the colour of the overlay to full blue colour(No opacity) with text on hover.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:
`<div style="font-size:40">(insert your text here)</div>`

You can change the size instead of the "40" as you want.